# What support does HTML5 provide for semantic markup and Semantic Web technologies?

Tags: html, semantic-web, semantic-markup

It seems that, as of right now, there is little to no support in HTML5 for semantic markup using RDFa or Microformats. I've done a little bit of reading, but if I were to start using HTML5 right now, what could I do to support semantic markup (such as microformats) and Semantic Web technologies (such as RDFa)? If I want to utilize these technologies now, should I stick with XHTML?

Comment: HTML Microdata (Draft) http://dev.w3.org/html5/md/ Microdata tutorial with examples: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/extensibility.html

Comment: If you've not already found it, see http://dev.w3.org/html5/rdfa/

Answer (score 5):

*(Some years have passed …)*

For semantically annotating your content in HTML5 documents, you can use Microdata, Microformats, and/or RDFa:

- [**Microdata**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/) is an extension to HTML5, but now merely a *W3C Working Group Note* (<s>and it will not become a *W3C Recommendation* in the foreseeable future</s> work started again in 2017: https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/). It’s still [included](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#microdata) (and potentially under development) in WHATWG’s *HTML Living Standard*.
- [**Microformats**](http://microformats.org/) (as in `class` values) are obviously supported as these don’t require any changes to the HTML language. Microformats (as in `rel` values) are supported as soon as they are registered in their own wiki under [existing rel values: HTML5 link type extensions](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions) (this is the place where [all link types have to be registered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19866312/1591669) for HTML5).
- [**RDFa**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-rdfa-core-20130822/) is an extension to various markup languages, [including HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-html-rdfa-20130822/). It can also be used in the form of the subset [**RDFa Lite**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-rdfa-lite-20120607/). All relevant specifications are *W3C Recommendations*.

(There is also JSON-LD, but I’m not adding it to the list because it doesn’t integrate with the existing markup, it’s a separate "blob", duplicating the content.)