# Schema.org: Use Microdata, RDFa or JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org

Are there any advantages/disadvantages in using a specific format for http://www.schema.org/Product? Something like "Searchengines understand Microdata better than JSON-LD"? I would like to use JSON-LD, because it doesn't mess-up with your html-code, but I'm not sure if it would be better concerning the searchengines to use Microdata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no general answer, it depends on the consumer of the data.

A specific consumer supports a specific set of syntaxes, and might or might not *recommend* a subset of these supported syntaxes.

Because search engines usually try to make sure not to get lead astray (e.g., a page about *X* claims via its Schema.org use to be about *Y*), it seems natural that they would prefer a syntax that couples the Schema.org metadata to the *visible* content of the page ([in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175699/1591669), this would be [Microdata or RDFa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669)); for the same reasons why many meta tags are dead for SEO.

However, this is not necessarily always the case. Google, for example, recommends the use of JSON-LD for a few of their features (bold emphasis mine):

- [Promote Critic Reviews](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/critic-reviews):

  > Though we **strongly recommend using JSON-LD**, Google can also read schema.org fields embedded in a web page with the microdata or RDFa standards.
- [Sitelinks Search Box](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview):

  > We **recommend JSON-LD**. Alternatively, you can use microdata.

Comment: Update: Google [now recommends](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38100293/1591669) JSON-LD for everything (except for the features that don’t support JSON-LD, which currently seems to be only the Breadcrumbs feature)

Comment: Do you know what the other search engines prefer? Also what if you use two standards ie JSON-LD and Microdata, is this discouraged and why?

Comment: @Bizmate: I’m not up to date with what other search engines support or recommend. Regarding using multiple syntaxes: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036600/1591669) (when describing the same item in both syntaxes) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668874/1591669) (when describing some items in one syntax, some items in the other syntax).