# What is the difference between Schema.org's WebSite vs WebPage type?

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, microdata

I was reading Google documentation on how to impletement [Sitelinks Search Box](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview). In the example, they use

```
itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite"
```

to implement sub-properties like `potentialAction`, etc.

However, after reading the schema documentation [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) it looks to me that `WebSite` is inferior to `WebPage`.

- They inherit the same properites from `CreativeWork`
- `WebPage` has its own properties, while `WebSite` doesn't

Is there a scenario where `WebSite` should be used / is preferable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`WebSite`](http://schema.org/WebSite) represents a web *site*, [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) represents a web *page* (like the difference between [`Blog`](http://schema.org/Blog) and [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting)).

The additional properties from `WebPage` (like `breadcrumb` and `mainContentOfPage`) wouldn’t necessarily make sense for `WebSite`.

Google’s Sitelinks Search Box uses `WebSite` because the search usually applies to the whole site, not just a single page.

Comment: So what if I need to put `WebSite` on body to use `potentialAction`, but I also want props from `WebPage`? Can I nest these items?

Comment: @gskema: Yes, you can have several items in a document (it doesn’t matter if you nest them or not, unless you have a property to relate them).

Comment: Still unclear to me on how to proceed. Should I maintain hierarchy and put `WebSite` on html or body once, and put `WebPage` once immediatelly after? Or should I use `WebSite` and `WebPage` multiple times whevever I need to put props of them?

Comment: Alos, take a look at this (might help) http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2014Apr/0291.html#start291

Comment: @gskema: It doesn’t matter if you use `html` or `body` or something else for your `itemscope`. The HTML5 hierarchy has no effect on the Microdata (it’s only relevant if you use Microdata properties to relate two items). So if you want to state some data about a webpage, use `WebPage`; if you want to state some data about a website, use `WebSite`; and if you want to state some data about both, use both. (Note that these don’t necessarily have to be about the current webpage/website, e.g., you could state something on *your* site about the `WebSite` with the `url` "`http://stackoverflow.com/`").

Comment: One final question (I hope you don't mind): is it ok to microdata about the same element in two different places (meaning that I declare it twice)? For example, declaring `WebSite` and then `potentialAction` somewhere and then `WebSite` again somewhere else (about the same Website).

Comment: @gskema: That is technically not forbidden, but [I’d recommend not to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28632901/1591669). In case of Microdata, its [`itemref` attribute could be used in such a case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28889281/1591669).