# schema.org structured data in visible elements

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

The two code fragments below will both be invisible for the user, but are parsed well in [GSDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#).

```
     <div>
          <div itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemscope>
            <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="http://schema.org/Book" itemscope>
              <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2001-01-15" />
              <meta itemprop="bookFormat" content="http://schema.org/Paperback" />
              <link itemprop="image" href="http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/plato-cover.jpg" />
              <meta itemprop="author" content="Plato" />
              <meta itemprop="numberOfPages" content="224" />
              <meta itemprop="inLanguage" content="English" />
              <div itemprop="review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope>
                <meta itemprop="name" content="Old is new again" />
                <meta itemprop="reviewBody" content="A lovely read." />
                <meta itemprop="author" content="O. Talp" />
                <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2001-01-16" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "WebPage",
          "mainEntity":{
                  "@type": "Book",
                  "author": "Plato",
                  "bookFormat": "http://schema.org/Paperback",
                  "datePublished": "2001-01-15",
                  "image": "plato-cover.jpg",
                  "inLanguage": "English",
                  "numberOfPages": "224",
                  "review": [
                    {
                      "@type": "Review",
                      "author": "John Doe",
                      "datePublished": "2001-01-16",
                      "name": "O. Talp",
                      "reviewBody": "A lovely read."
                    }
                  ]
                }
        }
    </script>
```

Now consider the code below, which contains structured data which is also visible to users; and it is parsed well in [GSDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#):

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemscope>
        <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="http://schema.org/Book" itemscope>
            <p itemprop="datePublished" content="2001-01-15">Published: 2001-01-15  </p>
            <p itemprop="bookFormat" content="http://schema.org/Paperback" />Format: Paperback </p>
            <img itemprop="image" src="https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato#/media/File:Plato_Pio-Clemetino_Inv305.jpg" >
            <p itemprop="author" content="Plato" >Author: Plato</p>
            <p itemprop="numberOfPages" content="224" >Pages: 224</p>
            <p itemprop="inLanguage" content="English" >Language: English</p>
            <div itemprop="review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope>
                <p><strong>Review</strong></p>
                <p itemprop="name" content="Old is new again" >Old is nieuw again</p>
                <p itemprop="reviewBody" content="A lovely read.">A lovely read.</p>
                <p itemprop="author" content="O. Talp">Author: O. Talp</p>
                <p itemprop="datePublished" content="2001-01-16">Published: 2001-01-16</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I would prefer the last code fragment, because it contains structured data *and* produces visible output. Nevertheless microdata seems deprecated, or will be sooner or later. What would be best practice to produce structured HTML data that is also visible for users?

Comment: Why do you think that Microdata is (or will be) deprecated?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I made a (probably mistaken) assumption, because schema.org does not always provide microdata examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microdata is not deprecated.

- WHATWG has it specified as [part of their Living HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#toc-microdata). W3C has it [specified in a Note](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/) (with a [new plan to publish it as Recommendation](https://github.com/w3c/microdata)).
- The Schema.org sponsors (still) support the three syntaxes JSON-LD, Microdata, and RDFa. They have no plans to deprecate any of these.
- Consumers of Schema.org data might of course support only a subset of these syntaxes, or other ones. Unless you want to support a consumer that you know doesn’t support Microdata, there is no reason not to use it.

  (By the way, the consumer Google recommends to use JSON-LD, but still supports Microdata and RDFa. There is [no reason to follow their recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38100293/1591669) if Microdata/RDFa works better for you, [unless you have to add it on the client-side with JavaScript](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/110150/17633)).

Each syntax has its advantages and disadvantages ([JSON-LD vs. Microdata vs. RDFa](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/328711/63183)).

If you want to mark up your existing content (instead of duplicating the content), you have to use Microdata or RDFa. Either one should be fine for your case ([Microdata vs. RDFa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669)).