# Is this use of structured data incompatible with JSON-LD?

Tags: microdata, json-ld, rdfa

StackOverflow has some good comparisons of Microdata, RDFa, and JSON-LD, especially in answers by "unor" in [2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/5803910), [2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28612357/5803910), [2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34245691/5803910), and [2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38100293/5803910).

Google [specifically states](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#structured-data-format) "Google recommends using JSON-LD for structured data whenever possible." But when I look at the page source of a Google search, the very first content of the page is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage" lang="en">
```

The `itemscope` and `itemtype` attributes in the `<html>` tag are microdata. So why is Google using microdata when it tells us to use JSON-LD? Is there something about the use of structured data in that tag that makes it unsuitable for JSON-LD?

Comment: Probably a different department. Microdata is still supported, and what you use is probably best decided by what is easiest for your system and what works on the systems you want to be seen on. Or it may be that in their case, microdata is more compact.

Comment: This is not necessarily the answer - it could be, or the answer could just be bureaucracy as Tony alludes to - but you should know that the question is based on a flawed premise: that what Google recommends for most developers is the same as what Google requires for itself. A company of Google's scale has different requirements and different needs than those of most other companies.