# What is the difference between metadata & microdata?

Tags: metadata, terminology, microdata

I am quite puzzled with these two terminologies. I know the basic meaning of metadata is **"data about the data"**.

Microdata means the **webpages are now more accessible to the search engines**.

But what separates these two terms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Microdata* is the name of a specific technology, *metadata* is a generic term.

Metadata is, like you explain, data about data. We’d typically want this metadata to be machine-readable/-understandable, so that search engines and other consumers can make use of it.

In the typical sense, metadata is data **about the whole document** (e.g., who wrote it, when it was published etc.). This goes into the [`head` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-head-element) (which "represents a collection of metadata for the Document"), where you have to use the [`meta` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) and its [`name` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-name) (unless the value is a URI, in which case you have to use the [`link` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) and its [`rel` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#attr-link-rel)), as this is defined to "represent document-level metadata".
Microdata is not involved here.

If the data is **about entities described in that document** (or the entity which represents the document itself), we typically speak of [*structured data*](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82219/17633). An example for such an entity could be a product and its price, manufacturer, weight etc.
[Microdata](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html) is one of several ways how to provide structured data like that. [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175699/1591669) are [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-in-html/), [Microformats](http://microformats.org/), and also [`script` elements used as data block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798784/1591669) (which can contain something like JSON-LD).

Answer (score 1):

Metadata (small m) is a general descriptive term, Microdata (big M) is the name of a particular technology.

Microdata is a particular kind of metadata that can be attached to a particular kind of data (namely HTML) in a particular way (as defined by W3C's Microdata spec).

Answer (score 0):

Metadata: using data to provide information about data. For instance, if you are collecting data about prices of different commodities and you added a small section at the top of the questionnaire to collect information about the name of the enumerator, time of interview, duration of interview etc., such information is a metadata.

Microdata: data from individual observations of interest.