# HTML5 = What is the diffrence between Metadata vs Microdata?

Tags: css, html, web

I literaly am going to pull my hairs out, Ive spend a whole day on this topic and I cant seem to grasp the concept. What is the diffrence between Metadata vs Microdata? and when do you use them?

Comment: Literaly spent about 6 hours and im still clueless about the diffrence

Comment: Do you have any more specific questions? This subject can be researched more by looking into SEO blogs and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are duplicates of this question: [What is the difference between metadata & microdata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319687/what-is-the-difference-between-metadata-microdata)

But to explain specifically. This page has the following metadata:

```
<title>html - HTML5 = What is the diffrence between Metadata vs Microdata? - Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">    
    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&amp;a">
    <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="HTML5 = What is the diffrence between Metadata vs Microdata?">
    <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="I literaly am going to pull my hairs out, Ive spend a whole day on this topic and I cant seem to grasp the concept. What is the diffrence between Metadata vs Microdata? and when do you use them?
">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000561/html5-what-is-the-diffrence-between-metadata-vs-microdata">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000561/html5-what-is-the-diffrence-between-metadata-vs-microdata">
```

It's just data describing the page content. Data that is meta.

Microdata on the other hand is a type of structured markup that tags certian entities on the page such as products, articles or reviews. For example : http://microformats.org/ or https://developers.google.com/structured-data/. Where you may be confused is what kind of effects this data has for the page. Both are related to SEO or social sharing. Meta data helps search bots gather information about the page. Microdata/Structured Data can relay certain information in a standard way to search bots or social sharing sites that can consume and display the data in a standardized manner.

Comment: Ahh, so basically meta helps search browsers and users to track down your page. While microdata does the same thing but every item that is specified to be a microdata will be displayed in the result of the search browser (eg; there are some links in google with pictures, reviews,etc)?

Comment: exactly, you can markup data with whatever they have structured markup for like video to get video thumbnails in search results: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/videos

Comment: thanks so much! I cant tell you how reliefed I am now hehe!

Comment: One more thing! I just came accros this code: <meta itemprop ="name" content = "website name">, my quesiton is, why is meta and micro together? what does this code mean :o