# Is there a relationship between schema.org and WAI-ARIA?

Tags: schema.org, wai-aria

Is there a relationship between schema.org and WAI-ARIA?
Is one a subset of the other? Are they different? Are there any commonalities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no relationship. Neither is a sub-set of the other.

Schema.org is intended to provide search engines with additional information about content, via microdata, RDFa, and JSON-LD. Within HTML you would use microdata. You can [read more on using microdata at schema.org](https://schema.org/docs/gs.html). There is no formal standards body behind it, it is defined by the major search engines.

ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications) is a bridging technology that allows authors to add additional information to HTML so that assistive technology can make better use of it. Ideally it will go away as browsers catch up. It has no bearing on search engines. It is maintained by W3C, [where you can read an overview on ARIA](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php).

Comment: "Within HTML you would use microdata" … [or RDFa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27175699/1591669).